# why my selection sort program is not working?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

```
public class first {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr[]={5,4,1,3,2};

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++){
            int smallest=arr[i];                     
            for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++){
                if(smallest>arr[j]){
                    smallest=arr[j];
                }
            }
            //swap
            int temp=smallest;
            smallest=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

i have done this problem by getting the smallest in terms of index number
and the program works properly .
but when i am taking smallest in terms of number present at index number ,
this program did not work.`your text`

Comment: well you need 2 indexes to do the sort the i index and the lowest number index and then you need to replace their positions with each other

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the smallest number index not the number it self so you know the positions to make the swap

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int indexOfSmallestNum = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[indexOfSmallestNum] > arr[j]) indexOfSmallestNum = j;
        }
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[indexOfSmallestNum];
        arr[indexOfSmallestNum] = temp;
    }
```